# VBA Open Workbooks File Not Found

Tags: vba, excel

I have some macros that were working previously like:

```
Sub test()
'
' test Macro
'

    Windows("_Macro_Duplicate Billing Templates.xltm").Activate

    Src2 = Sheets("Parameters").Range("C12").Value

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Src2

End Sub
```

where I indicated "D:\Users\D801878\Int'l\Billing\2017_03\Billing Template_International_2017_03.xlsx" in cell C12

This was working in 2016 till now. Now I get the error that "D:\Users\D801878\Int'l\Billing\2017_03\Billing Template_International_2017_03.xlsx is not found."

Did anything change in terms of naming the filepath and filename?

Comment: are sure that the file really is no longer found in the directory as you've defined it

Comment: @ScottHoltzman yes the file is definitely there. i've checked the path and filename many times and it is as i have defined it.
now, it's not hardcoded but that should not be an issue?

Comment: cell C12 has formula " =$C$6&$C$7&"_"&$B12&".xlsx" "
where C6 = " ="D:\Users\D801878\Int'l\Billing\"&D2&"_"&F2&"\" "
D2 = " 2017 "
F2 = " 03 "
C7 = " ="Billing Template_International_"&D2&"_"&F2 "
B12 = [country]

Comment: Please check all the cell values and formulas for extraneous spaces. What you typed in the comment above does not look quite right, but it could just be typos. I'm especially interested in the "03" due to the leading 0. How are you doing that?

Comment: Check the format ".xlsx"

Comment: Have you checked that "Billing Template" hasn't got an underscore like all the other spaces in the filename?

Comment: Hi All, thanks for all your replies.
@Winterknell, "03" refers to the month. I formulated it that if month is single digit, then F2 is "0"&E2 where E2 is month().

Comment: @Marius, i have checked that the file extension is indeed ".xlsx"

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald, checked, "Billing Template" doesnt have an underscore.

Comment: what continues to baffle me is that i have not changed the filenames, cos the macro is looking for that, but it "suddenly" stopped working... i will scrutinise the filename again...

Comment: Hi all, I have solved the mystery! Feeling happy and silly at the same time. @Winterknell was spot on - i missed one *@$&^ space after "template"! and I just realised cos it's a new template from the regional office...
Sorry for the wild goose chase guys. I'm still very much a novice in VBA. Lots more to learn from the Masters here.
Thanks again!

Comment: HIi All,
I've met another error...
this is my code:

Comment: `
Src1 = Sheets("Parameters").Range("C11").Value
Tgt1 = Sheets("Parameters").Range("D11").Value
Src2 = Sheets("Parameters").Range("C12").Value
Tgt2 = Sheets("Parameters").Range("D12").Value
Src3 = Sheets("Parameters").Range("C13").Value
Tgt3 = Sheets("Parameters").Range("D13").Value
`

Comment: `On Error GoTo 1
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Src1
Range("M6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InvDate
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Tgt1, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

1   On Error GoTo 2
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Src2
Range("M6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InvDate
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Tgt2, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

2   On Error GoTo 3
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Src3
Range("M6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InvDate
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Tgt3, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False`

Comment: Sorry i dunno how to make the codes look "nice" and right...

issue is both Src1 and Src3 are not in the folder. BUT the code skipped Src1 without error and will stop at Src3 with a runtime error

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to make like this:

I'm supposed the value `03` means the number of the month witch is `march` or `mar`, so:
Put in `C12` the date `mar.2017` and use the following code:

```
Dim y As Integer
Dim m As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim link As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Parameters")
y = Format(ws.Range("C12"), "yyyy")
m = Format(ws.Range("C12"), "mm")

link = "D:\Users\D801878\Int'l\Billing\" & y & "_" & m & "\Billing_Template_International_" & y & "_" & m & ".xlsx"

Workbooks.Open link
```

Comment: @chase Try Now, I put the underscore after `Billing`